# Dictionary ContainsKey() Doesn't compare string values

Tags: c#, dictionary, split

I'm a noobie to C# and don't understand why `ContainsKey()` won't return true with the values `bid_amount` and `bid_amount`.

I have a long string `("key=value, key=value...")` that is split on `,` and then `=` created into a dictionary. But when I test for a known key in the dict `bid_amount` it always returns false.

Is there a way to compare values using ContainsKey()?
What exactly am I missing?

```
string[] responseStringSplit = responseString.Split (new []{ ',' });
Dictionary<string,string> responseDict = new Dictionary<string, string> ();

foreach (string word in responseStringSplit) 
{
    string[] splitString = word.Split (new[]{ ':' });
    if (splitString.Length > 1) 
    {
       responseDict.Add(splitString [0],splitString [1]);
    } 
    else 
    {
       Debug.Log ("CouldNotSplit:" + word);
    }
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in responseDict)
{
    Debug.Log (entry.Key + "=" + entry.Value);
    if (responseDict.ContainsKey ("bid_amount")) 
    {
      Debug.Log ("found bid amount");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your input string?

Comment: Are you sure tha there is such string? I mean, no spaces around it? Perhaps you could add a Trim before adding the key/value pair around _spitstring[0], [1]_

Comment: Works for me. Check your input. See here for a working example of your code with a valid input: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SxOJ8M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your input, you've got a space between your `,` and your `key`. Try calling .Trim() on `splitString[0]` and `splitString[1]` before you add it to your dictionary.

```
responseDict.Add(splitString[0].Trim(), splitString[1].Trim());
```

Comment: Yes, there was a trailing space and .Trim() fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at the code and input you have 2 problems:

1. You first split by "," whereas your input code is "someText, someTextAfterSpace" - So split by ", ".
2. Then you split by ":" whereas your input code is with "="

Code should be:

```
//split by ", " (plus the space) to avoid that problem (or use trim)
string[] responseStringSplit = responseString.Split (new []{ ", " });

//split by "=" instead of current ":" (Or change input string from having '=' to ':')
string[] splitString = word.Split (new[]{ '=' });
```

Besides changing that, adding `Trim()`s and `ToLower()` for the key is of course welcome in order to avoid problems with white spaces and uppercase/lowercase